# How to $watch changes from ng-repeat checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Consider the below scenario.

I have div which will be generated based on the array length (in this case it is 3).

Here, I wanted to watch for the checkbox value whenever it is changed. But, it is possible with `ng-change`, but when I click the `second div checkbox` (first checkbox is checked/toggle event), now `$watch` is not triggered.

I wanted to watch the first checkbox value whenever it is changed. (without using `ng-change`, because I have another scenario to make first checkbox as true when second div checkbox is true. so `ng-change` will not work in this case)

Where am I missing?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.roomIndex = 0;
 $scope.ROOMS = [
 {
   "name" : "abc",
   "id": 1,
 },
 {
   "name" : "def",
   "id": 1
 },
 {
   "name" : "ghj",
   "id": 1
 }
 ];
 
 $scope.$watch('room.check', function(newval, oldval){
  console.log(newval);
 });
 
 $scope.changed = function(room){
  console.log(room);
 }
 
 $scope.call = function(){
 
  if($scope.ROOMS[$scope.roomIndex].check){
    $scope.ROOMS[$scope.roomIndex].check =   false;
  }
  else{
  $scope.ROOMS[$scope.roomIndex].check =   true;
  }

 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-init="roomIndex = $index" ng-repeat = "room in ROOMS track by $index">
    <p>
      {{room.name}}
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="room.check" ng-change="changed(room)"/>
</div>
<div>
  Second div checkbox <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check2" ng-change="call(roomIndex)"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll probably have to watch the collection itself (`$scope.ROOMS`) with object equality (last parameter set to `true`). Be careful with this, though, as it can quickly become a memory and performance hit if the collection is large or contains complex objects.

Comment: I tried that too and cannot achieve this

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it and it works. `$scope.$watch('ROOMS', function(){...}, true);`

Comment: not working, i have created a fiddle, you can also check https://jsfiddle.net/dineshmick/7jwad4ek/20

Comment: When setting the watch variable you don't include `$scope`. Check my previous comment for the proper format (and don't forget to pass `true` as the last parameter since it is an array and you need Angular to use object equality). Honestly, though, it really seems like using `ng-change` is a much better option here.